# Android need fullwidth drawerlayout. it should appear and disappear when hamburger icon is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, drawerlayout, android-drawer

**xml code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background_01"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/actionDrawer"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hamburger" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/actionHome"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="This is Home page"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </TextView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topbar">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/app_background_01"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="left">
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/textSelectHandle" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**kotlin code**

```
package com.example.testdrawer

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import com.example.testdrawer.databinding.ActivityFullscreenBinding

class FullscreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityFullscreenBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityFullscreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setListeners()
    }
    private fun setListeners() {
        binding.actionDrawer.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                binding.drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
            } else {
                binding.drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Behaviour Required**
1- Home screen comes in start
2- When click on hamburger icon the drawerlayout should come with full height and width also containing hamrbuger and home icons.
3- When click on hamburger icon the drawerlayout should close and the home screen should come.

**Issues**
1- drawerlayout is not full width and required functionality is not achievable.

The below is the homescreen
[image]

Want the drawerlayout to fully occupy the screen as in the design its having full background and icons on top.
[image]

When I tried Drawerlayout constraint in xml toptotopof parents I was not able to click on hamburger icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add negative margin for the sides of your drawer layout to fill the whole screen.

```
android:layout_marginRight="-64dp"
```